# Can I programmatically determine the make and model of a handheld device and belt printer?

Tags: c#, windows-xp, compact-framework, windows-ce, handheld

Working on some legacy code with Windows CE using Visual Studio 2003 running in an XP Mode Virtual Machine on Windows 7.

I am writing some code that runs on handheld devices, and need to know which make and model they are. Is there a built-in call I can make to query the handheld device as to its identity?

Similarly, I will programmatically deduce the make and model of the belt printer that the handheld device is attached to, so that code can branch based on these details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try getting the Device Name and ID with calls to [`KernelIoControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms886729.aspx) calls passing in `IOCTL_HAL_GET_DEVICEID`.  [There's an example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172516%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). That *might* be able to determine the handheld model.

As for the printers, it's unlikely you can tell the difference - though it depends on how exactly they're connected.  If it's serial there's no way.  If it's USB, it's unlikely unless they use different drivers.  If it's networked, then it's not going to happen.  If it's Bluetooth, *maybe* the device name has a pattern based on model you can use.